# Typescript - Getting the type of properties in my interface to avoid using any

Tags: typescript

I have an interface like:

```
interface OktaUser {
    someId: number;
    email: string;
    email_verified: boolean;
}
```

I then have some method to get these properties out as requested:

```
async getOktaUserProperty(key: keyof OktaUser): Promise<any> {
        // Do some stuff

        return oktaUser[key];
}
```

Is there any way I can avoid using `any` in the return, I could manually do `Promise<number | string | boolean>` but makes it a little cumbersome to maintain.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=51#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIGsxwKoGdrIDeAUMmcrgPYC2EAkgCYBcyIArtQEbQDcp5EanGAAbFrjBRQAcz7lkg4SID6AN2jAYwCM2SdKlERDgg+AX2LEYbEAjDBKIZNIhgMWPNAAKUSgAdoMABPAB4AFQBpCCCFAA9IEAZcZHRoyhg0TBx8KAA+AApUoJZI6IBKFnds6ABtUqCAXSJ+MgRHCWRYyqzPKGQAXmb5eSpaRhYARgAGABoW4cVRFgByGANlueGBIVE1DS0dFkk2CE3yMz55qFc2KCdYmqKG4gtiNpAOmMGXNx6cn38gSC+WWixEyzKPGQAHpoRRJDI3u0wMgAF4DZyuKq9AEBKDBEGjegMCFQ2GsDjcKBAA) It uses several features of TypeScript including generics and [index types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types).

```
interface OktaUser {
    someId: number;
    email: string;
    email_verified: boolean;
}

function getOktaUserProperty<TKey extends keyof OktaUser>(key: TKey): OktaUser[TKey] {
    const x: OktaUser = {
        someId: 10,
        email: 'foo',
        email_verified: true,
    };

    return x[key]
}

const y = getOktaUserProperty('email'); // string
const z = getOktaUserProperty('someId'); // number
```

Comment: Awesome that works - but I have no idea what it means lol
So are we declaring a generic function, with some `TKey` being a property of `OktaUser`, - however at that stage why is the `extends` keyword needed?

Comment: @userMod2 It takes some time to get the hang of it. There are detail in the `index types` link. Reading that section and understanding what it means will take you a long way to becoming a TypeScript expert.